# Remove 'Print Shipping Labels' action from Sales/Shipments Grid

Tags: magento-2.1, grid, xml, uicomponent, shipment

I am trying to remove the 'Print Shipping Labels' mass action from the Sales->Shipments grid in the admin area. This grid is setup as a UI component. I have created the following blank file inside my custom extension:

```
app/code/Vendor/ExtensionName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_shipment_grid.xml
```

I cant work out what XML is needed to remove the action. Does anyone know if its possible to remove a mass action from a uicomponent grid using XML?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best way to do this but is working:-

Create your admin theme and in that override the header.phtml file located at
Custom/admintheme/Magento_Backend/templates/page

```
require(['jquery'],
    function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {

            setInterval(hidePrintLabel,1000);
            function hidePrintLabel(){

                $( "li span:contains('Print Shipping Labels')" ).css( "display", "none" );

            }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<action name="print_shipping_label">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">print_shipping_label</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Print Shipping Labels</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="adminhtml/shipment/massPrintShippingLabel"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
```

Remove or comment this action from sales_order_shipment_grid.xml

Comment: Im not sure editing files inside the vendor folder is the right approach unless I am missing something?

Comment: No you can use this file in your custom module : app/code/Vendor/ExtensionName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_shipment_grid.xml

Comment: I was looking for a cleaner way to do this if possible because if the file is changed in a future upgrade then the updates will not be applied to the site. Are you not able to reply a remove flag to the action in the XML?